# Netbeans Autocomplete just randomly stopped working?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm running netbeans v12 and the autocomplete function just randomly stopped working. I've tried clearing the user cache data and that hasn't helped either. I cleared %LOCALAPPDATA%\NetBeans\Cache.